# Retrieving data from database to a different view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sqlite

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application_%28Xcode_4%29

I have found this sqlite tutorial on google and it worked great for my requirement.
In this tutorial both adding and retrieving data are done on the same viewcontroller. but i want that 'save' method in the tutorial in one viewcontroller and 'find' method in the other.

And also someone tell me whether this tutorial is an effective way to save data or not.because this is the easiest tutorial I found so far.

Answer (score 1):

You might also create a new class ,or use inheritance (upper class) call it for example "SqliteClass" 
that have both the 'Save' and 'Find' method

then you can use any method in SqliteClass from any other class ,,
in case you don't want to use inheritance make sure that the methods in SqliteClass are "class" methods the one begins with "+" not"-" 
I used both ways and they work just fine ..

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can to that. you can have n number of view and can save data from any view controller.

check this tutorial.

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/